# Resttemplate response in ????? how to resolve this

Tags: resttemplate

API response content-type coming as utf-16 but it should be in utf-8 format..am using spring 3.1.0 version. Am passing header and body to resttemplate. Responce comming like ???????????
Help me on this

My Code

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("AuthenticationToken", authenticationToken);
    headers.set("ExactSubscriptionId", subscriptionId);``
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
HttpEntity<String> entity2 = new HttpEntity<String>(lis.toString(),headers2);
ResponseEntity<String> irnResponce2 = restTemplate2.exchange(Url, HttpMethod.POST, entity2,String.class);
```

i have used resolve this below code

```
restTemplate2.getMessageConverters().add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

and also tried

```
headers.add("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
```

but in spring 3.1.0 version StringHttpMessageConverter not allowing constructor
I need to resolve in this version only plz anyone help on this

Answer (score 0):

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
   List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> c = restTemplate.getMessageConverters();
        for(HttpMessageConverter<?> mc :c){
            if (mc instanceof StringHttpMessageConverter) {
                StringHttpMessageConverter mcc = (StringHttpMessageConverter) mc;
                mcc.setWriteAcceptCharset(false);
            }
   }



 HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
  headers.setAcceptCharset(Arrays.asList(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
  HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(jsonPayload, headers);

  restTemplate.postForEntity(postResourc`enter code here`eUrl, entity, String.class);
```